# Get a list of all running applications and get their PIDs?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it possible to get a list of all current running applications.

The closest I got was to use `[NSRunningApplications runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier]` but this only returns if it has an exact bundle identifier of what i supply it.

After I get the list i hope to get the pids of each by going `[NSRunningApplication processIdentifier]` on each element in the array.

And `[NSRunningApplication bundleIdentifier]`'s

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];` should do the trick for you.

**Edit:** If you want the PIDs, you need to go through every element (`NSRunningApplication`) in the `NSArray` returned from `runningApplications`.  Then you can access the `processIdentifier` property from the element.

For example, this would be grabbing the first running application.
`[(NSRunningApplication*)[[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] objectAtIndex:0] processIdentifier]`.

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thank you very much!! :)